# Custom Field Type - Data not passing to the view

Tags: custom-fields

I'm trying to create my own custom field type, however, when I go to load the view, the var's within my display_field function, are Undefined. All I'm trying to do, is Load a view file, then in the view, loop through and array.

Example:

```
function display_field($data)
    {
        $entry_id = $this->EE->input->get_post('entry_id');
        $query = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT * FROM exp_channel_images WHERE entry_id = '$entry_id'");

        $channelImages = array();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
            {
               array_push($channelImages, $row);
            }
        }

        return $this->EE->load->view('index', $channelImages, TRUE);
    }
```

Then, my view file is called index.php, and is located under:

/third_party/channel_images_sources/views/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for new entries the get_post(entry_id) probably isn't set (check and verify it before running your query). Second, the view loader **extracts** the vars array passed to it, and your array doesn't have keys. instead of passing $channelImages array, try passing it inside an array, something like array('chanimg' => $chanimg)

See example below, and the part "adding dynamic data to the view"
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

```
$data = array(
  'chanimg' => array()
);

$entry_id = $this->EE->input->get_post('entry_id');
if ($entry_id > 0){
    // query
    // $data['chanimg'][] = $row;
}

return $this->EE->load->view('index', $data, TRUE);
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Now I simply reference "$chainimg" in the view, and my data is there!

Answer (score 1):

The display_field function of field type will not load view file so you need to return the data / content which you would like to show at edit or publish forms and SAEF.

Like:

```
function display_field($data){
/***
other code
**/

return "<div>SOME DATA or VARIABLES</div>";

}
```

Comment: While true that you need to return data/content from the display_field method for the publish screen. It is possible to use a custom view (say a whole table or a map with javascript) and fetch that view with the second parameter of load view set to true (return as string) and pass that data along from display field.